# NTLM Authentication - is it simply a prompt(challenge), or does it actually authenticate?

Tags: java, security, web-applications, ntlm

I have a (java) web-application, and i have enabled NTLM Authentication.

When the logon prompt is presented by the browser in our (windows) intranet environment.
The behavior i see is:

NTLM prompt does not seem to be doing any authentication at all, i am able to type any random string in userid prompt and it allows the user to proceed into the application. The prompt never fails the user.

So, what do i need to check at the server end to find if authentication succeeded or not?

Comment: Please update the question with the details on how you enabled NTLM for your Java application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NTLM Authentication in a Web Application (java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830957/ntlm-authentication-in-a-web-application-java)

Comment: Suggest should have been continued in that question. You *do* have to connect to the Active Directory domain controller and verify the type 3 response that the browser has sent you, and this is HARD - don't attempt to do it yourself, re-use an existing library. (Even then, it is really annoying.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind NTLM auth is that the logged on user can proceed with connection without explicitly entering his username and password again. So whatever your application asks you is irrelevant (as you can see it yourself) and instead your system credentials are used.

Answer (score 0):

[NTLM authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM) has been broken for a number of years -- NTLM 2 shipped with NT 4, so hopefully people have moved on by now. If you want to use Active Directory login information, you should use Kerberos instead.