# Apply ADF Security with WWW-Authenticate NTLM

Tags: oracle-adf, ntlm, www-authenticate

I am developing an application in Oracle ADF that needs to apply a user login authentication.

The security protocol followed by the company is to read the username from the Windows Credentials and checking if that username exists in a certain database table. The applications that use this policy are usually JSP or .NET applications and do this by setting `response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM")` which pops the authentication dialog then reads the username entered and calls an SQL query to check if that username exists in the database and checks the role.

I need to implement that in ADF and I cannot find a way to do so. All the information that I've found is regarding configuring realms in the WebLogic and using an SQLAuthenticate on the Weblogic server.

I tried putting the code in a managed bean using beforePhase on the view and it didn't work.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three ways in order to accomplish this (one of them will cost you money!)

1. Check this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830957/ntlm-authentication-in-a-web-application-java) and this [java library](https://code.google.com/p/ntlm-java/) and create a Servlet for Authentication behavior, but this way you won't be able to make ADF Security works, and you have to implement Security yourself
2. Check [this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/blogbypuneeth/entry/configure_kerberos_with_weblogic_server) and [that article](http://biemond.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/single-sign-on-with-windows-kerberos-on.html) to enable Kerberos with Weblogic, and in your ADF application in web.xml make the security as CLIENT-CERT, if you managed to use that ADF Security should work fine
3. Consider using Oracle Single Sign On solution which will require you paying for license

PS: All this solution will only work on IE & Chrome out of the box, you will have to make some [configurations](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/2014-firefox-ntlm-authentication) to make it work with firefox,

Comment: I went with the first approach and it's working great! Thanks