# NTLM token verification in Java

Tags: java, ntlm, ntlmv2

I want to verify/authenticate the `type3message` that `Apache httpd` server has received from the client browser and passed to `Apache Tomcat`. I am just not able to figure out how to do it.

I have the following mechanism in place as depicted [here](http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html). `C` is the client. `S1` is the `Apache httpd` server and `S2` is the `Apache Tomcat` server.

```
1. C -> S1  GET ...
2. S1 -> C  401 Unauthorized
         WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
3. C -> S1  GET ... (type 1 message)
         Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAA7IAAAoACgApAAAACQAJACAAAABMSUdIVENJVFlVUlNBLU1JTk9S
4. S1 -> C  401 Unauthorized (type 2 message)
         WWW-Authenticate: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAACAAAAAAAAACgAAAABggAAU3J2Tm9uY2UAAAAAAAAAAA==
5. C -> S1  GET ... (type 3 message)
         Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAHIAAAAYABgAigAAABQAFABAAAAADAAMAFQAAAASABIAYAAAAAAAAACiAAAAAYIAAFUAUgBTAEEALQBNAEkATgBPAFIAWgBhAHAAaABvAGQATABJAEcASABUAEMASQBUAFkArYfKbe/jRoW5xDxHeoxC1gBmfWiS5+iX4OAN4xBKG/IFPwfH3agtPEia6YnhsADT
6. S1 -> S2 Challenge - TlRMTVNTUAACAAAAAAAAACgAAAABggAAU3J2Tm9uY2UAAAAAAAAAAA==
         Token - TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAHIAAAAYABgAigAAABQAFABAAAAADAAMAFQAAAASABIAYAAAAAAAAACiAAAAAYIAAFUAUgBTAEEALQBNAEkATgBPAFIAWgBhAHAAaABvAGQATABJAEcASABUAEMASQBUAFkArYfKbe/jRoW5xDxHeoxC1gBmfWiS5+iX4OAN4xBKG/IFPwfH3agtPEia6YnhsADT
7. S2 -> S1 Authenticated or Not Authenticated
8. S1 -> C  200 Ok or 401 Unauhorized
```

In the `Apache Tomcat` server, I want to authenticate the user. I have the `challenge/type2message` the `Apache httpd` server sent to the client in step 4 and the `type3message` that the client responded with in step 5.

I am doing the following, however, I get an exception. I am missing some basic stuff like setting the configuration and/or the environment but for some reason my brain refuses to work.

```
 NtlmPasswordAuthentication np = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(t3m.getDomain(), t3m.getUser(), serverChallenge, t3m.getLMResponse(), t3m.getNTResponse());
 InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getByName("domain");
 UniAddress ua = new UniAddress(ia);
 SmbSession.logon(ua, np); // exception is here
```

Am I doing it correct? I want to authenticate the user.

Comment: To clarify: you're `S1` is authenticating the client.  Once that has finished, you're trying to pass the auth messages that the client delivered to `S1` over to `S2` to further authenticate them?

Comment: @EdwardThomson - The server `S1` is just picking the `NTLM` token from the client. `S1` then passes the type3message and the challenge it had sent to the backend Java server `S2`. The server `S2` has to then use the challenge and the type3message to authenticate the user.

Comment: But `S2` didn't create the challenge?  If not, `S2` will not validate the responses to another server's challenges.

Comment: The challenge is random and created by the server S1. `S1` and `S2` are our Frontend and Backend servers, they are not the Active Directory or LDAP servers.

Comment: @EdwardThomson - Can you help me with my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56367401/java-how-use-ntlm2-authentication-in-spring-mvc